# Function return type depends on optional argument

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function which returns array of promises of certain type - Order[]

But there's case when i pass value callback, which has function-type, inside params, then function should return ReturnType of callback, not Order[]

I tried this code

```
type Order = { timestamp: number }

type CBT<T extends (orders: Order[]) => any> = 
  T extends undefined ? Order[] : ReturnType<T>

const fetchOrders = <T extends (orders: Order[]) => any>(params: { 
  callback?: T
} = {}) => {
  const promises = [1, 2].map(() => Promise.resolve([] as Order[]))
  if (params.callback) promises.map(promise => promise.then(params.callback!))
  
  return promises as Promise<CBT<T>>[]
}

const n = fetchOrders({ callback: (orders: Order[]) => orders.length })
const n2 = fetchOrders({})
```

and i expect that

- n will have type Promise[] and it is really
- n2 will have type Promise<Order[]>[], but instead i get
  Promise[]

How can i write this to get correct type in case when callback is skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```typescript
type Order = { timestamp: number }

type OrderCb = (orders: Order[]) => any

function fetchOrders(params: {}): Promise<Order[]>[]
function fetchOrders<T extends OrderCb>(params: { callback?: T }): Promise<ReturnType<T>>[]
function fetchOrders<T extends OrderCb>(params: { callback?: T }): Promise<Order>[] | Promise<ReturnType<T>[]>[] {
  const promises = [1, 2].map(() => Promise.resolve([]))

  if (params.callback) promises.map(promise => promise.then(params.callback))
  
  return promises
}

const n = fetchOrders({ callback: (orders: Order[]) => orders.length })
const n2 = fetchOrders({})
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/mxoexN)

Comment: Thanks a lot - overloads for Me is the most unclear and not obvious part of TS still